# Function pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock/timedrdlock with relative time-out

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I am developing an application cross-platform in C/C++ for Solaris(Sparc), AIX(PowerPC) and Red Hat Linux(x86_64) in which we use the pthread library.

I need to use synchronization timeout for readers/writers so I am using the function pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock/timedrdlock, for that you must use the absolute time.

This is my current implementation and works fine:

```
bool nLec1Esc::close (unsigned int timeout){
    struct timeval now;
    struct timespec strtimeout = {0};

    // Get the current time
    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

    // Add time for timeout value
    strtimeout.tv_sec  = now.tv_sec;
    strtimeout.tv_nsec = (now.tv_usec+1000UL*timeout)*1000UL;           

    return (pthread_rwlock_timedwrlock(rwlock, &strtimeout) == 0);
}
```

I'm trying to improve implementation looking to improve performance and prevent calls to gettimeofday each time and use a fixed relative time.

I've seen that is available for Solaris function pthread_rwlock_reltimedwrlock_np, working with relative timeout value.

Do you see any way to improve this implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: up! Any pthread_rwlock_reltimedwrlock_np for linux implementation?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as reltimedwrlock either in POSIX standard or in GNU/Linux implementation. This is a known shortcoming of the standard. The shortcoming roots in differences between the system time and a "monotonic" time which should be used for I/O timeouts.

POSIX doesn't force an OS to have a monotonic timer, so pthread library doesn't offer a reliable way to set timeout on wrlock wait operation. Your way is unreliable too, because your implementation would hang if system time is changed (see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.programmer/mu0WtJs8rkk) discussion for details).

I think the most portable way to set timeout on wrlock operation is to create an explicit timer (in your favorite way) to call pthread_rwlock_destroy from another thread or from a signal handler.